# ListView with items of variable height

Tags: android, android-listview

I have to display a list view that contains items inflated from the same layout template but has a variable height. I've created a subclass of `BaseAdapter` that returns these views in a `getView()` method, but as I scroll the `ListView` the height of the scroll thumb changes and also some random items become unselectable. How can I fix this?

```
public class NewsfeedActivity extends ListActivity{
Vector<NewsEntry> entries=new Vector<NewsEntry>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.newsfeed);
setListAdapter(new NewsAdapter());
}

public class NewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
public int getCount() {
return entries.size();
}
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return entries.elementAt(pos);
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View v=getPostView(entries.elementAt(position), NewsfeedActivity.this, convertView);
  // This method simply fills the view with data
  // height of the returned view is different, but layout is same.
return v;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file?  My first thoughts run towards setting the height simply to "wrap_content" which will allow whatever is sitting in that particular View (it could be a layout, textView, etc., etc.) to grow or shrink as needed to contain their data / children.  But, let's see the layout file before making too much unwarranted advice.

Comment: The height is already set to "wrap_content" and views I create are of correct size. My problem is that ListView behaves incorrectly when items doesn't have the same height.

Comment: Try extending a View to make your own that will be used by the ListView .. I do this all the time because I need custom painting or other functionality.  The 2 things of interest will be the onMeasure() and onDraw().  Based on what you're saying the onMeasure() will be where you'll handle the specific size (height) for any given View.